# Asp.Net Core 3.1 references doesn't work because of tilde "~"

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, reference, asp.net-core-3.1

We use `<link>` to reference a file for CSS or other static files. like this:

```
    <link href="~/assets/css/style.bundle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

or to import a javascript library. like this:

```
<script src="~/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
```

The address of all these references starts with "~/..." which means the wwwroot folder.

When I run the project (on IIS Express or any other) these addresses being like this:

[image]

And it always works.
I believe the browser doesn't understand address which starts with tilde "~". SO, at some point, something removes all ~ from addresses before sending the page to the browser.

recently, a cloned a repository that has a lot of CSS and js references. Non of "~" doesn't been removed when I run the project.

[image]

And the point is when I remove the "~" from the address in the inspector of chrome, the source being loaded and works properly.

I tried to delete them manually. but it caused a lot of other issues and errors.

What can I do to avoid sending "~" to the browser? or somehow solve this issue.

Comment: What is the file type of the cloned page?

Comment: @MikeBrind An asp.net core 3.1 MVC web application project. references are in the shared _layout page. unfortunately, I cant share the repository but I can share the .cshtml page if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how helpful this "answer" might be, but I also ran across the same issue for an ASP.NET Core 2.1 solution. Nothing I did to the solution itself would resolve the issue, so I deleted my copy of the solution and re-cloned. Then it started working again for me.

I have no idea what the root cause was or why this would fix it, but hopefully it works for you/others too.